# Unset post term in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I use this to set post terms from a custom taxonomy 'mois':

```
wp_set_post_terms(  $post_id, array ($term_id['term_id']), 'mois' ,true);
```

It works fine, but how coul i do the inverse : unset a post term ?
I don't want to delete the term but only unset it from the post.

Comment: Your question would benefit from additional background. It's appearance in the post is most likely due to page template. Please show the relevant info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for your question. You can just use **wp_remove_object_terms** hook to unset the terms using post id.

**Here is the example of how you can do it:**

`$tag = array( 5 ); // Array of terms to be unset.`

`wp_remove_object_terms( $post_id, $tag, 'mois' );`